# How to use Python Queues in multiple functions

Tags: python, queue

I am having an issue with accessing the queue object within my class in multiple functions, the following code might show you what i am trying to do;

```
import MySQLdb
import socket, sys
from struct import *
import threading
import sched, time
from datetime import datetime
from copy import deepcopy
import Queue
IP = {}

class QP:

 def __init__(self):
        self.jobs = Queue.Queue()

    # this function runs every 10 seconds
    # and processes any queued data.
 def processQueue(self):
        print(self.jobs.qsize())
        time.sleep(5)
        if self.jobs.empty():
            print("No items in queue")
        else:
            IP_TEMP = {}
            IP_TEMP = self.jobs.get()
            IP_TEMP_QUEUE = {}
            IP_TEMP_QUEUE = IP_TEMP
            try:
                cnx = #connect to database
                cursor = cnx.cursor()
                for k, v in IP_TEMP.iteritems():

                    #there is some code here, but its not the issue

                    try:
                        cursor.execute(add_packet, data_packet)
                        cnx.commit()
                        print("Task Done")
                    except:
                        print("Query failed, skipping")
                        break
            except:
                self.queueJobs(IP_TEMP_QUEUE)

            IP = {}
            self.jobs.task_done()
            self.processQueue()

    # this function is called by other modules to add data
 def queueJobs(self, data):
        self.jobs.put(data)
        print(self.jobs.qsize())
        return True
```

This is how i call the queueJobs method in the other modules:

```
self.process.queueJobs(IP_TEMP_QUEUE)
```

Now, the main issue is that the `processQueue()` function always returns that there is no jobs in the queue, even though they have been added below in the `queueJobs()` function.

Any help would be great!

Comment: According to the current indentation `queueJobs()` is *not* part of the class you defined

Comment: Could you show the code that calls the queueJobs() and processQueue() methods?

Comment: Sorry, seemed to be an issue with what i pasted in, changed now and it was apart of the class on my IDE

Comment: I added how i call them, but i cant really show any more code.

Comment: When you call queueJobs(), and it prints out your qsize(), what does that number look like? Is it always zero? always 1? incrementing? none of the above?

Comment: Always incrementing, but when i print it on processQueue(), its always 0

Comment: Are you creating more than one instance of class QP? Are you sure you're calling queueJobs() and processQueue() from the same instance? It sure seems like you're not reading from the same queue that you're adding to.

Comment: Well i create a instance of QP on the UDP and TCP modules that call queueJob, would it be bound to that separate module?

Comment: I can't say for sure, without seeing more code. In your example  you call self.process.queueJobs(IP_TEMP_QUEUE). Somewhere above that you must do process = QP(). To process the queue,you have to call process.processQueue(). Each instance of QP will have its own queue. you have to call queueJobs() and processQueue() methods on the same instance, otherwise they won't be looking at the same queue.

Comment: How could I have the same instance on two models?

Comment: A couple of ideas: Create the instance outside both modules, and pass it in to both, or create it in one and pass it to the other.